# Heroku Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, heroku

App repo: https://github.com/calebkish/DevConnector

To preface, my web app has been pushed to Heroku.

I'm trying to successfully build my MERN web application onto Heroku, but when I visit my app page (https://safe-fortress-83003.herokuapp.com/), it just returns the error "Not Found" from the root GET response. When I view the logs for my Heroku app, this error displays when a root request is sent:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'`

So, I went into my local CLI and ran `heroku run bash`, viewed the current files and directories, and found that /app/client/build/ didn't exist. This leads me to believe that it isn't being generated using my heroku-postbuild script defined in my [package.json](https://github.com/calebkish/DevConnector/blob/master/package.json) (no idea why it isn't running when I `git push heroku master`). Out of desperation, I ran `npm install && npm run build` inside my client folder (where my react app is located), and now the build folder containing index.html is on my heroku app. When I try to view the app however, I still get an error of "Not Found".

I've been trying to debug this for hours, no idea what is wrong. The static files (build folder) are being defined inside [server.js](https://github.com/calebkish/DevConnector/blob/master/server.js) if you'd like to take a look.

---

EDIT: I just removed build from .gitignore and pushed to heroku, and my app works now. So the main problem is that my heroku-postbuild script isn't running even though the name is clearly defined in this documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution for that particular problem
first you create a folder with name of app and put your client folder  on it and go for server.js file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
   //static folder add
    app.use(express.static('app/client/build'));
    app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname , "app/client/build", "index.html"));
     });
   }
```

after that you change the package.json file

```
 "scripts": {
     "start": "node server.js",
     "server": "nodemon server.js",
     "heroku-postbuild": "cd app && cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm 
       install && npm run build"
     },
```

after that you run your file that works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).